# PDF View in ReactJS web application

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, pdf-generation, jspdf

In ReactJS web application using MUI component library, a 'View' button is embedded in data table, on click of which based on the api response base64 data, file url will is generated through this:

```
const dataUrl = `data:application/pdf;base64,${base64Data}`;
setPdfData(dataUrl);
```

Now, for pdf view in same page as pop up, I am embedding this iframe in return statement:

```
<iframe
 title="PDF Viewer"
 src={pdfData}
 style={{ height: '975px', width: '100%' }}
 >
```

But is there any way to add **close icon** in pdf view to close the pdf, since right now it is taking whole space on page popup with no option to close it, and iframe doesn't has internal attribute to have close button. How to implement it?

I have tried adding Modal component but in its content, pdf is not being rendered properly.